# Get Elasticsearch Score in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

Elasticsearch provides a score field if you do a get request via cURL.

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "tweet",
  "_id": "123",
  "_score": 4.2,
  "firstName": "Max"
  "lastName": "Mustermann"
}
```

Is there a way to get this score inside symfony. I am wondering if FOSElasticaBundle provides a function similar to the one below to get the score.

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.article');
$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

$fieldQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$fieldQuery->setFieldQuery('title', 'I am a title string');
$fieldQuery->setFieldParam('title', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addShould($fieldQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching with FOSElasticaBundle, you'll get a `Elastica\ResultSet` with `Elastica\Result` inside. You can iterate on those results, they have a `getScore` method to get what you need.

```
$resultSet = $this->store->search($query);

$results = $resultSet->getResults();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $score = $result->getScore();
}
```

Alternatively, you can get the score with this: `$result->getParam('_score');`

Answer (score 1):

If trying to change this from within a class that extends `FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository`, consider using `$this->findHybrid()`. That method returns an array containing `HybridResult` objects. Each `HybridResult` in turn contains both the transformed entity and the result data (including a score).